# Why is my jquery animate() function not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  //alert("Window scroll event detected.");
      
  if ($(".image-container").visible(true)) {
   //alert("if ($(\".image-container\").visible(true))");
   $(".image-container").animate({background-position:center 100%}, 300);
  }
      
 });
 
});
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}

.p-wrapper {
 height:130vh;
 background-color:wheat;
 color:coral;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.image-container {
 height:200px;
 background-image:url(http://www.galleonnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/creative-mind-brain-wallpaper-870x489.jpg);
 background-size:100% auto;
 background-position:center 0%;
 color:transparent;
}

.another-p-wrapper {
 background-color:pink;
 color:green;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.visible/1.1.0/jquery.visible.min.js"></script>


<div class="p-wrapper"><p>I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.I am a paragraph.</p></div>
 
 <div class="image-container">.</div>
 
 
 <div class="another-p-wrapper"><p>I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. I am a another paragraph. </p></div>
```

OR

**[JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/sfwjk31f/)**

In this SSCCE, if you uncheck the second comment, and reload it, you can see that the jQuery plugin is working correctly, i.e. ASA any part of the `.image-container` becomes visible, `if ($(".image-container").visible(true))` returns `true`

**So the problem lies with the statement: `$(".image-container").animate({background-position:center 100%}, 300);`. This isn't doing anything. The question is why?**

The effect I want is that as the window is scrolling down, the background image of should animate its `background-position` from `center 0%` to `center 100%`. So that the user can see the bigger image set as background of a smaller div (heightwise), while they are scrolling the window.

Comment: use quotes `$(".image-container").animate({"background-position":"center 100%"},300);`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I don't think that matters, because they haven't used quotes in the examples in the [official documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to animate each background position like:

```
background-position-x, background-position-y
```

Like this:

```
  $(".image-container").animate({
    'background-position-x': '100%',
    'background-position-y': '50%'
  }, 300, 'linear');
```

Also, in your example, this `$(".image-container").visible(true)` is throwing an error..

Comment: That isn't working for me. Could you try it on the code example I posted?

Comment: The js fiddle has a JS error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).visible is not a function". If you remove that line is working... with my example.